# <error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'> when compiling with const int

Tags: c++

I am getting the following errors when compiling the below code:

```
3>c:\hedge\hedge\hedge\AisTarget.h(22) : error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
3>c:\hedge\hedge\hedge\AisTarget.h(22) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

---

```
#if !defined(AisTarget_h)
#define AisTarget_h

#include "GeneralAviationItems.h"
#include <string>

namespace HEDGE {
    using namespace GeneralAviation; 

    class AisTarget : public WaypointLatLon {
        public:
            static const int NO_DATA = -1000; //here is the error
    };    
} // end namespace HEDGE

#endif
```

Comment: Your `#if !defined` can be replaced with `#ifndef` btw.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `static const int NO_DATA = -1000;` with `enum { NO_DATA = -1000 };`? In that case, you have a very old compiler. Please don't tell us you're using Visual Studio 6 ;-)

Comment: using visual studio 2008 express. no worries guys, this is just for simulator.

Answer (score 33):

It is likely that `NO_DATA` is already defined as a macro elsewhere, and so it is expanding into something that does not agree with the compiler's notion of a variable name. Try re-naming `NO_DATA` to something else.

If there were no such conflict, the code as it were would compile fine, as demonstrated [here](http://ideone.com/8FJ4e).

Comment: That's why I don't use uppercase identifiers in C++. Too many reckless-named macros in standard libraries. windows.h is horrible

Comment: @kotlomoy: Yes, that is generally good practice. At a minimum, upper case identifiers should have some distinguishing prefix or postfix to avoid such collisions (preferably in mixed or lower case).

Comment: came here because of NO_ERROR, thanks winerror.h. NO_DATA is btw defined in WinSock2.h

Answer (score 5):

Even if this post has its age: The error can generally occur when multiple redefinitions, even regardless of upper/lower case, coexist. **This includes potential preprocessor definitions in the solution's *.vcprojx* file!**. Consider something like

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>$(Configuration);%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

in the above mentioned file. Now, having "Debug" and "Release" configurations you will most probably run into some problems and a potential source for the C2059 error. I experienced exaclty this dilemma.

Comment: wow, this happened to me just now and thanks to your post, i was able to fix it in no time.